# How to grep for this string that contains an equal sign?

Tags: bash, shell

Below is the string I am trying to grep for this in the bash shell:

```
'#Hostname=sometext.company.com, sometext.company.com' filename
```

I want to only find the string if it matches that exact pattern. I already tried the command below and a few others.

`grep -Fx "#Hostname=sometext.company.com, sometext.company.com" filename`

Comment: have you checked if your target line has leading/trailing spaces? since you  have `-x`, grep matches whole line.

Comment: Why do you think the `=` has any role to play in this working or not? Can you show the **exact** input and the **exact** command you are running and what you get as output? Can you match **any** lines in the file currently? Does your file have DOS line endings?

Comment: If you don't want to perform a regex match, why are you using `grep`? Use [`fgrep`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fgrep-command-in-linux-with-examples/amp/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify the `-x`option on purpose?

```
grep -F '#Hostname=sometext.company.com, sometext.company.com' filename
```

most likely is what you want. Also, it's better to put single quotes instead of double quotes, just in case your search pattern happens to contain special shell characters.

Comment: Is `-F` really necessary? There are no multiple fixed strings separated by *newlines* to be considered in the match. It will work just as well without the `-F`.

Comment: I wanted the `-x` option to match the exact words used.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Historically, `-F` dumbed down `grep`into behaving like `fgrep`, which understood fixed strings only (no regular expressions) and therefore could be implemented with a more simplified and faster running pattern matching algorithm. Today, the point is probably moot; on some system, `fgrep`, `egrep`etc. are symbolic links to one and the same `grep`executable, and the differences in execution speed are probably not significant anymore for many applications with today's hardware.

Comment: @AnthonyFreeman Which "words" do you mean? The example will match the string `#Hostname=sometext.company.com, sometext.company.com` – is this not what you wanted?

Comment: @Guido I am trying to find the string only if it has the `#` in front of the string. For instance, the search should not give me anything if it is `Hostname=sometext.company.com, sometext.company.com` instead of `#Hostname=sometext.company.com, sometext.company.com`. I hope that clears it up.

Comment: @AnthonyFreeman Given an input file containing two lines: `Hostname=sometext.company.com, sometext.company.com`and `#Hostname=sometext.company.com, sometext.company.com`, the above `grep`commands return the second line for me (with or without -Fx options, doesn't matter), which I understand is the result you expect. Can you edit your question to include some more content of your test file as well as the actual grep commands you tried and which didn't work?